# Which to use...REST, ASMX, WSE or WCF?

Tags: wcf, web-services

I have a Windows Service which performs a certain function, and then needs to send that information off to a webservice for processing. The webservice is hosted by a remote web application. I am trying to ascertain the best way to call the webservice(s) as each web application might be only 2.0, or 3.5 etc. In my windows service, I am defining each "client" in the app.config, e.g.

```
<Client WebServiceUrl="http://location.com/webservice.svc" Username="" Password="">

</Client>
```

The web application must implement two web services that are required for my windows service to run, however not sure the best way to implement the "rules" for the web application.

**EDIT:**

I'll try and rephrase..
The Windows Service runs every 30 seconds and obtains a list of information. The service supports multiple "clients" as shown above. When each client process is run, the data is collected and is then needed to be sent to the supporting web application.

The windows service does not know what to do with the data, it is just sending it. Each web application for a client would be in different locations, and could possibly be built in 2.0, 3.5, PHP, etc. All the windows service cares about, is that when it performs its processing for a client, it is able to send the data to the webservice location defined in the app.config of the windows service.

What I'm trying to determine is how to connect to the webservice (which I'm leaning towards WCF, however Basic or WS not sure), and what rules need to be defined for the web application in how to build the response.

If the Windows service is to support php applications etc, WSHttpBinding would not be an option, which would mean BasicHttpBinding would then work. The other thing to decide is whether or not to utilise a RESTful service or SOAP service.

Hope this makes more sense.

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't quite understand the question.  Is your reference to 2.0, 3.5, etc.. above a reference to .NET Framework versions?  Are you saying that your Windows Service might have to call a variety of different web applications, each implemented in different ways?  Or are you implementing the web services and trying to figure out the best approach?

Comment: yup, micky maybe you can restate the question, because it's not clear to me either.

Comment: ok so when you say "Client" you really mean "paying customer", and in fact the "Client" is what we would call a "server" in distributed systems design.

Comment: And what does it mean when you say "when each client process is run...".  I thought the Windows Service just ran - it collects data unrelated to Clients/customers.  Then it ships data out to the Clients/customers.  What does it mean to run a client process?

Comment: Say I have two processes, one which adds up numbers, and another which subtracts numbers (as a small example). Both are in the windows service, and each client(paying customer) defined in the config, utilises those processes. Each client initialises a new thread to run those processes. The processes are run every x seconds and when the process is complete sends the results to the webservice defined in the config.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not really clear on what you are doing.

It seems like you have 3 things: A Windows Service, and then a web service, hosted in a web app.
I think your question is, *what to use, REST, ASMX, WSE or WCF, when interconnecting the Windows Service app with the remote web service*.

ASMX, WSE and WCF are alternative programming models for the web service.  REST is not a programming model.  It is not like the other three.

ASMX and WSE will require that you use Web services and SOAP.
WCF can allow you to use Web services and SOAP, REST (XML or JSON) over HTTP, or a binary format over TCP, among other options.

Because it is flexible and current technology, I'd recommend WCF.  ASMX is now termed "legacy technology" by Microsoft.  Doesn't mean it won't work, but it will not get updates.  (Much like WinForms versus WPF).  WSE is no longer in mainstream support, as far as I know.  For these reasons, I wouldn't recommend starting a new project on WSE, nor on ASMX.

---

WCF is more general than ASMX and can seem more complicated, for that reason.  But once you make some choices and zero in on what you want (for example choose HTTP and REST, or choose binary and TCP), it's more powerful.  WCF can be used as the programming model on both the client or sender (in your case,  the Windows Service, I guess) and/or on the server (the web service hosted in the web app).

Using WCF on the client side does not imply you must use it on the server side, and vice versa.  On the other hand, if you control the source code on both ends, I would recommend using WCF on both sides.

As for "how to implement the rules for the web app" - I don't understand what you are asking there. Maybe if you are more specific on the question there, someone will be able to help out.

---

Update: Based on your additional explanation, I'm going to suggest you look at the REST stuff in WCF for .NET 3.5.  In PHP it's very easy to implement a REST-style service, and with WCF, the same is true for .NET.  Now in your case the Windows service is the *client* and it is sending out a request, an update request, to various *servers* that reside on your customers' networks.  According to REST principles, I'd make those outbound requests PUTs or POSTs, depending on the semantics of the call.

Then you could ship some example service code to your (uppercase) Clients, to get them started on building what they need to receive your outbound PUT/POST messages.

Security is a concern though. You didn't mention it at all, which is surprising.  Security is not one of those things best deferred, so that you "add it on later".  You should think about it early - it may affect the protocol choices you make.  For example, if you need to mutually authenticate the clients and servers (the latter at your "uppercase" Clients' networks), then you may want to go with SOAP, which gives you good options on the protocol side for security.  Secure Web services extensions (WS-Sec, etc) are well supported in WCF, but not sure about the status of this capability in PHP.

Comment: +1 for recommending WCF over ASMX/WSE - when starting a new project today, there's no point is using outdated technology like ASMX and WSE when a much more powerful and flexible successor is available!

Comment: Although I did not mention security in my original explanation, this is definately being thought about, as the information being sent is sensitive. Based on research and other posts, we will have to set a minimum requirement on how the paying customer is to implement their web services.
Authentication is a must.

Comment: I agree with marc_s, after moving from WSE to WCF, I'll never go back.